# Cannot read properties of null (reading '0') const [Rank,setRank] = useState(JSON.parse(user)[0].Rank)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgUtl.png)I have a problem deploying a website. I declare usestate Rank. but in console.log error Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

How do I solve this problem?

But when running localhost is fine, it's when deploying.

ex.Code
const [Rank,setRank] = useState(JSON.parse(user)[0]?.Rank);

Comment: can you plz post what your user looks like?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without seeing this statement within the context of the rest of your component its difficult to debug. Please add the rest of the code as a [mcve]. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Please add code of your navbarMain.jsx